# How to diplay multiple lists as a table, with each list having different index length

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I display a table, if I have 3 lists, all each having different length without using external libraries. (PYTHON 3)

There is the data input:

```
list_1 = ["Ae Ae", "Bee Bee", "Ce Ce", "Dee Dee"]
list_2 = ["Af Af", "Bf Bf"]
list_3 = []
```

Here is the out put:

```
    e NAME      |     f NAME       |      g NAME
=============   |  =============   |   =============
Ae Ae           |  Af Af           |
Bee Bee         |  Bf Bf           |
Ce Ce           |                  |
Dee Dee         |                  |
```

Thanks. 
(External libraries means the one that doesn't come default with python 3. (eg: import random is fine).

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please be aware this is not a code-writing service. We can help solving specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please [edit] your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [ask] page for details how to help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'll let you get fancy with the margins

```
from itertools import zip_longest

list_1 = ["Ae Ae", "Bee Bee", "Ce Ce", "Dee Dee"] 
list_2 = ["Af Af", "Bf Bf"] 
list_3 = [] 

for strs in zip_longest(list_1, list_2, list_3): 
    for s in strs: 
        if(s is not None): 
            print(s, end="") 
        print("\t|", end="") 
    print("")
```

Tabs aren't aligned here for some reason, but they look nice in my python and ipython shells.

Answer (score 0):

I use the same `zip_longest` as @curlycharcoal to group elements in row but later I use

- list comprehension to replace `None`,
- string formatting to set the same width for all items
- `"|".join()` to create string with full row

---

```
from itertools import zip_longest

list_1 = ["Ae Ae", "Bee Bee", "Ce Ce", "Dee Dee"] 
list_2 = ["Af Af", "Bf Bf"] 
list_3 = [] 

print('''      e NAME      |     f NAME       |      g NAME
  =============   |  =============   |   =============''')

for row in zip_longest(list_1, list_2, list_3):

    # put empty string instead of `None`
    row = ["" if item is None else item
              for item in row]

    # format every item to the same width
    row = ["  {:14}  ".format(item)
              for item in row]

    # join all items in row using `|` and display row
    print("|".join(row))
```

Result

```
      e NAME      |     f NAME       |      g NAME
  =============   |  =============   |   =============
  Ae Ae           |  Af Af           |                  
  Bee Bee         |  Bf Bf           |                  
  Ce Ce           |                  |                  
  Dee Dee         |                  |
```

---

**EDIT:**

Similar way I can create header. But this time I use `^` in string formatting to center text.

And I use `"="*14` to create `=============`.

```
header = ['e NAME', 'f NAME', 'g NAME']

row = ["  {:^14}  ".format(item)
              for item in header]

print("|".join(row))

row = ["  " + "="*14 + "  "
          for item in header]

print("|".join(row))
```

And later I can use variable `width` instead of `14` and it will use it in place of internal `{}`

```
"  {:^{}}  ".format(item, width)
```

This way I can easily change `width` (eventaully I could use `max()` and `len()` to find longest word in all table or in every column and use different widths for every columns - but I will not try to do this here)

---

```
from itertools import zip_longest

list_1 = ["Ae Ae", "Bee Bee", "Ce Ce", "Dee Dee"] 
list_2 = ["Af Af", "Bf Bf"] 
list_3 = [] 

header = ['e NAME', 'f NAME', 'g NAME']

#width = 14
width = 20

row = ["  {:^{}}  ".format(item, width)
              for item in header]

print("|".join(row))

row = ["  " + "="*width + "  "
          for item in header]

print("|".join(row))


for row in zip_longest(list_1, list_2, list_3):

    # put empty string instead of `None`
    row = ["" if item is None else item
              for item in row]

    # format every item to the same length
    row = ["  {:{}}  ".format(item, width)
              for item in row]

    # join all items in row using `|` and display row
    print("|".join(row))
```

---

More about string formatting on https://pyformat.info/

---

**BTW:** If you don't want two spaces before first colum then use spaces in `"  |  "` instead of spaces in `"  {:^14}  "`

```
from itertools import zip_longest

list_1 = ["Ae Ae", "Bee Bee", "Ce Ce", "Dee Dee"] 
list_2 = ["Af Af", "Bf Bf"] 
list_3 = [] 

print('''    e NAME      |     f NAME       |      g NAME
=============   |  =============   |   =============''')

for row in zip_longest(list_1, list_2, list_3):

    # put empty string instead of `None`
    row = ["" if item is None else item
              for item in row]

    # format every item to the same width
    row = ["{:14}".format(item)
              for item in row]

    # join all items in row using `|` and display row
    print("  |  ".join(row))
```

Result (without two spaces on the left side)

```
    e NAME      |     f NAME       |      g NAME
=============   |  =============   |   =============
Ae Ae           |  Af Af           |                
Bee Bee         |  Bf Bf           |                
Ce Ce           |                  |                
Dee Dee         |                  |
```